# Should Insecure Direct Object Reference be taken seriously when developing public RESTful APIs?

Tags: api, rest, owasp

I went reading [OWASP's 2013 Top-10](http://owasptop10.googlecode.com/files/OWASP%20Top%2010%20-%202013.pdf), and found out that *Insecure Direct Object Reference* ranks 4th. However, when I tried to study further on the some existing public RESTful APIs, it turns out Facebook and World Bank doesn't even bother about it. Both are simply using direct object references. As you can see with the examples below:

**Facebook API call**

> http://graph.facebook.com/5

**Word Bank API call**

> http://api.worldbank.org/countries/us?format=json

Does that mean we shouldn't take seriously Insecure Direct Object Reference when developing public RESTful APIs?

Answer (score 5):

Directly from the OWASP guide:

> How Do I Prevent This?  
>   Preventing insecure direct object references requires selecting an approach for protecting each user accessible object (e.g., object number, filename):
>   1.Use per user or session indirect object references. [...]
>   2.Check access. [...]

Facebook and the World Bank chose option 2 instead of option 1.